# E-commerse app managed from website

Tags: java, android, web, e-commerce

I want to write pizza delivery application.
It consists of 2 parts:
1) native android app - that lets users to browse and order pizzas
2) web-site for pizza shop owners, to see orders.

Which technology should I use to build web-page?
SHould I use MVC framework like Sprint Struts2 or smth else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring MVC is a good choice of framework, since it can handle so many parts of the application (Data persistance, security and MVC) altough it may be alittle overkill for a small application.

A possible stack could be:

Database: MySQL or MongoDB
Application Server: Glassfish or Tomcat
Server side: Spring MVC (with usage of Spring DAO and Spring Security)
Client side: JSP (With HTML/CSS/JS)

This could also be done with the MEAN stack or any other but I assume you would want to stick to Java-based technologies.